# How to create a std::thread using abstract class an abstract

Tags: c++, stdthread

```
#include <thread>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public :
    virtual void intiliaze(int x,int y) = 0;
};

class B : public A {
    public :
    virtual void intiliaze(int x, int y) {while(true){ std::cout << "Hello World "<< x <<" "<<y<<std::endl;} }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
 A* ptrA;
 int x=1;
 int y=2;
 std::thread th(&A::intiliaze,ptrA,x,y);
 th.join();

}
```

I get a segmentation voilation with the above code. I am trying to create an abstract class with one derived class.  Using that abstract class to run a thread is my requirement. Today it is one derived class but in future I will expand for other operations

Comment: What is `ptrA` pointing to?

Comment: What role does `class B` fill in your example code? You define it but never use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ptrA` is just a pointer and it needs an object to point to. Since, this pointer is created on `stack` ([automatic storage class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)), it might be holding garbage value (called [wild pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer)) and when your program tries to access the object (which doesn't exist because you have created it) using your pointer, you are getting segmentation fault.

You can create that object dynamically (using `new`) or statically.

Try this:

```
A *ptrA = new A();
```

Or

```
A obj;
std::thread th(&A::intiliaze, &obj, x, y);
th.join();
```

Comment: Thanks this helps. But the same in visual studio is showing a tuple error ??

Comment: I get something like thisSeverity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2661  'std::tuple<void (__cdecl slssm::DataManager::* )(slssm::ClientBlockData &),slssm::DataManager *,slssm::ClientBlockData>::tuple': no overloaded function takes 3 arguments ssm_dbservice c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\memory 2539

Comment: My Input is something like this   mQueryHandlerThreads[blkData.mLocalId] = std::thread(&DataManager::closeDb, dbmang, blkData);

Comment: That's a different code and you need to ask a different question

Comment: Created a different question here is the link to that

Comment: *"Try this:

`A *ptrA = new A();`"* -- This fails to compile (as does `A obj;`) because `A` is an abstract class.